# Что такое в LyX команда:Ветка?

Tags: lyx

В меню **Вставка** есть подменю **Ветка**. Что это такое?

Comment: Попробуйте и узнаете. В чем то проблема возникла?

Comment: Да, собственно, проблемы уже нет. Долго копался, прилично узнал, теперь вот делюсь. Честно говоря, очень удивлен, что вы не поняли.

Answer (score 0):

Вот я дошел до этого подменю, оно раскрылось. Там левой кнопкой мышки щелкаю пункт *Добавить новую ветку* (там 2 пункта, я щелкаю нижний). В появившемся диалоговом окне ввожу имя создаваемой ветки, нажимаю кнопку `Ok`. Я так понял, что в имени создаваемой ветки не должно быть пробелов. После нажатия кнопки `Ok` в окне LyX, в котором все это совершается, появляется следующая область:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Эта ветка появляется *неактивной*. Это значит, что если я что-то напишу перед веткой, затем я какой-то текст впишу в прямоугольник ветки и продолжу повествование после ветки, то в `.pdf`, образующемся из этого файла `.lyx`, часть текста, находящаяся в красном прямоугольнике, будет просто отсутствовать. Чтобы включить эту часть в `.pdf`, навожу мышку на слово *Ветка*, там, плюс-минус около этого слова, щелкаю правой кнопкой мышки и выбираю левой кнопкой мышки пункт *Активировать ветку*. В зависимости от используемого файла `.mo` этот пункт может называться по-разному, но всегда в выпадающем меню он стоит первым.