# Как в LyX использовать программу Asymtote?

Tags: lyx

Вот в файлы .tex можно вставлять коды на языке Asymptote, вставленные в соответствующие окружения, которые (коды) в результатирующем `.pdf` будут преобразованы в соответствующую графику. А можно ли что-то подобное делать в программе LyX?

Answer (score 1):

А делается это очень просто: открываем программу LyX. Идем **Документ>Настройки>Преамбула LaTeX**. Вписываем туда

```
\usepackage{asymptote}
```

возможно, с некоторыми опциями пакета asymptote, нажимаем кнопку `Сохранить`. Все, начинаем писать в основном окне программы LyX нужный нам текст. Как только дошло дело до вставки кода asymptote, [вставляем ветку, активируем ее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1063917/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2-lyx-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0), в ветку вставляем код ТеХ `Ctrl`+`l`) и только в этот блок начинаем писать

```
\begin{asy}
...
\end{asy}
```

где на месте многоточия пишем код Asymptote ровно таким же образом, как мы это делаем в каком-нибудь файле `.asy`. Например, выглядеть это может так:
[image]
Снимок сделан после первого экспорта в PDF(pdflatex). Обратите внимание на путь к папке, обведенный в нижней части окна программы LyX красным цветом. Вот когда я обрабатываю обыкновенный файл `.tex` в каком-нибудь тоже обыкновенном редакторе LaTeX, например, в TeXworks, все файлы, попутно при этом возникающие, такие, как `.log`, `.aux` и т. д., создаются в одной папке с этим  файлом `.tex`. В случае же экспорта в какой-нибудь формат в программе LyX в одной папке с обрабатываемым файлом `.lyx` образуется только `.pdf` все остальные возникающие при этом файлы (а сначала происходит экспорт в `.tex`, а затем на этот файл `.tex` натравляется какой-нибудь бинарник имеющейся на компе реализации ТеХ, подключенной (хотя, необязательно) к программе LyX) складываются в пакпка, путь к которой имеет формат, подобный формату пути, обведенного красной рамкой на фото. Например, в этот раз я LyX установил после программы MiKTeX. Так подключенность LyX к MiKTeX выразилась в том, что, я, когда после установки LyX, полез в **Инструменты>Настройки...>**, там, в текстовом поле *Префикс PATH:* среди прочих, был путь `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` - путь к папке с бинарниками, упомянутой мной выше установленной на компе реализации ТеХ. Однако наличие пути к этой папке в этом текстовом поле не является обязательным: я в предыдущей, тоже Windows7, системе, устанавливал LyX, когда еще не был установлен MiKTeX, так, несмотря на то, что пути к той папке в том текстовом поле не было как до установки и настройки MiKTeX, так и после этих операций, LyX функционировал нормально. Так вот, при обработке бинарником образовавшегося файла .tex все файлы, попутно при этом возникающие, такие, как `.log`, `.aux` и т. д., также создаются в одной папке с этим  файлом `.tex`.) помещаются в папке, путь к которой содержится в области окна программы LyX, появляющейся после нажатия **Вид>View Source**. Для демонстрации формата пути к такой папке, я на фото и обвел этот путь красной рамкой. Переходим в эту папку, запускаем из этой папки командную строку, выполняем в этой строке команду

```
asy *.asy
```

И делаем еще один экспорт в PDF(pdflatex). Вот теперь все готово: открываем созданное `.pdf` и наслаждаемся качеством графики, обычно ожидаемого там, где используется программа Asymptote. А ветка нам в этой всей истории потому, что без ее использования иногда графика в `.pdf` получается не в том месте, где стоит генерирующий ее код в `.lyx`. Впрочем, я недавно придумал способ вставки кода Asymptote в файл `.lyx` без использования веток, но об этом я расскажу на странице, более близкой к этой теме.